# How can I get git-gutter:next-hunk to NOT loop around at buffer bottom?

Tags: magit, functions

As per the title, I would like to stop processing at the end of a buffer and not loop around to the top. I find it easier to keep track of what I am doing that way. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at `git-gutter:next-hunk` and don't think it is possible to prevent it from wrapping around.

(This doesn't have anything to do with Magit.)

Comment: @mpersico Could you please accept the answer?